# Flask - Save session data in database like using cookies

Tags: python, flask

I am creating a web app using Flask.

I wonder if it is possible to save user session data like

```
session['ishappy'] = true
```

in database like it's done in Django using SessionMiddleware where you have options to choose between cookies and database.

And if it is what should I import to my Flask app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you implement your own Session and SessionInterface by subclassing flask defaults. Basically, you need to define your own session class and a session interface class.

```
class MyDatabaseSession(CallbackDict, SessionMixin):

    def __init__(self, initial=None, sid=None):
        CallbackDict.__init__(self, initial)
        self.sid = sid
        self.modified = False
```

The above class will now have a **session id (sid) that will be stored in the cookie**. All the data related to this session id will be stored in your mysql database. For that, you need to implement the following class and methods below:

```
class MyDatabaseSessionInterface(SessionInterface):

    def __init__(self, db):
        # this could be your mysql database or sqlalchemy db object
        self.db = db

    def open_session(self, app, request):
        # query your cookie for the session id
        sid = request.cookies.get(app.session_cookie_name)

        if sid:
            # Now you query the session data in your database
            # finally you will return a MyDatabaseSession object
     
    def save_session(self, app, session, response):
        # save the sesion data if exists in db
        # return a response cookie with details
        response.set_cookie(....)
```

Also, you can define a model for storing session data:

```
class SessionData(db.Model):
    def __init__(self,sid,data):
        self.sid = sid
        self.data = data
        # and so on...
```

The following snippets should give you an idea:

https://github.com/fengsp/flask-snippets/blob/master/sessions/redis_session.py

https://github.com/fengsp/flask-snippets/blob/master/sessions/sqlite_session.py

https://github.com/fengsp/flask-snippets/blob/master/sessions/mongodb_session.py

Comment: Is it possible to use it without redis and e.g. on MySQL database?

Comment: Because I use MySQL and SQLAlchemy and I am wondering how to connect sessions to them.

Comment: yes it is possible. You just need to ensure that you have open_session() and save_session() methods implemented where you read/write the mysql database.

Comment: Ok, so should I then implement a model for Sessions in e.g. models my which contains a key-e.g. user_id, expiration time and blob?
And while saving the session all the data, that are held "in the browser" while the user is logged in, should be encoded with the Secret Key and saved in db as I understand , yes?

Comment: I have added some sample code/pseudocode to give you an idea. They important thing to note is that the session id itself needs to be in a cookie and the actual data in the database. This way, the request object can just pass a signed cookie with the session id only.

Comment: I kind of understand the structure, but what details should be returned after the session is saved?
Because I am saving the data in DB with sid got from my browser and the data handled in one way or the other, so what I should put in the cookie afterwards? Something like "last saved at" or "success save"?

Answer (score 3):

You should check out [Flask-KVSession](http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-KVSession/), which is self-described as

> a drop-in replacement for Flask‘s signed
>   cookie-based session management. Instead of storing data on the
>   client, only a securely generated ID is stored on the client, while
>   the actual session data resides on the server.

Which basically describes traditional server-side sessions. Note that it supports multiple database backends:

> Flask-KVSession uses the [simplekv](http://github.com/mbr/simplekv) package for storing session data on a variety of backends.

See the [Example Use](http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-KVSession/#example-use) for an example of what to import and how to configure it.

Answer (score 0):

One of colleagues recently posted the post, which explains how to work and share the user sessions. Hope that helps:

- [Django, Flask, and Redis: Sharing User Sessions Between Frameworks](http://bit.ly/1g52E0G)