# Transfer Beaker Memcache into SqlAlchemy (MySQL)

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask, beaker

I work with Flask and want to create some user sessions working on database.

Thanks to some help I found this snippet http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/61/

```
from flask import Flask, request
from beaker.middleware import SessionMiddleware

session_opts = {
'session.type': 'ext:memcached',
'session.url': '127.0.0.1:11211',
'session.data_dir': './cache',
}

app = Flask(__name__)       

@app.route('/')
def index():
   session = request.environ['beaker.session']
    if not session.has_key('value'):
    session['value'] = 'Save in session' 
    session.save()   
    return "Session value set."
else:
    return session['value']

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.wsgi_app = SessionMiddleware(app.wsgi_app, session_opts)
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I have problems converting the example above into working SQLAlchemy running code. Not easy to find a tutorial for that.
All I've got is http://beaker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/sqla.html#module-beaker.ext.sqla

I know that session.type and url should be changed for ext:sqla and valid sql string to the database. But what's next?

Comment: I know the beaker sessions is no longer used/updated/managed. You can take a look at this to get ideas http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17694469/flask-save-session-data-in-database-like-using-cookies/17702517#17702517

Comment: What is now used instead of beaker? Dogpile?