# How to maintain state during Flask AJAX requests

Tags: ajax, python-3.x, flask, pythonanywhere

I created a Flask web page (*within PythonAnywhere*) requesting data in a polling situation via AJAX calls.

There are some complex object structures that cannot (easily) be jsonified and need to be maintained during the life of that page.

On my Windows PC I created an object in app and just read/updated as needed. That paradigm does not work in PythonAnywhere (*nor do I believe it to be an optimal solution anyway*).  PythonAnywhere does not support redis or memcached (*so that route is taken away*).  I could write it out to SQLite but have a feeling there are other options.

Any ideas on the best approach to access/modify my Flask objects during the AJAX calls?

My program is constructed like:

```
@app.route('/view_page')
@login_required
def view_page(program_selection):
    create_object=cc(current_user)
    render_template('myview.html', somevars=current_user.username)

@app.route('/_myajax_call')
@login_required
def ajax_call():    
    # Need to get create_object here
    some_data = some_function(create_object)
    return jsonify(result=some_data)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18873050/how-to-pass-complex-objects-across-view-functions-sessions-in-flask

Comment: @PJSantoro - Your suggested link ultimately recommends using  Flask-Cache [link](http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Cache/). I only have the *simple* or *filesystem* option available to me which rely on pickle. Pickle will not accept objects (classes, etc.) hence I will need to serialize them. I was trying to get away from that .. did I interpret that correctly?

Comment: OK, it appears that PythonAnywhere has some issues with multiple web workers/threading in my situation which is the bulk of the problem.  There is not simple solution in this case. Not sure WebSockets is available either. I still need to work this problem on my side. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't be more helpful. This general issue of object serialization creeps up in enough ways doing web development that I try and avoid the dependency of passing complex data structures around. If indeed there is an easier way to do this I'd be excited to learn.

Comment: PJ ... I went down the polling route because WebSockets isn't a PythonAnywhere option.  I have a solution now (not elegant) .. but as you stated, I'm removing all dependencies to make my state situation a 'non-issue'. Thanx.