# Access attributes of object in multiple routes

Tags: python, oop, flask

```
@app.route('/a',  methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def a():
    form = data(request.form)

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        job = Job()
        job.title = form.title.data

        return redirect(url_for('users.b'))


@app.route('/b',  methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def b():
    #access here the job.title previous defined
```

I know that I can pass parameters to url_for, but isn't what i am looking for. Basically access the previous defined object attributes. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTTP is a stateless connection, meaning a user being redirected to /b from /a will only be able to pass information via HTTP headers, cookies and URL parameters.

To solve this particular problem, you'll want to save the information set in `job.title` into a database on the host (i.e. [Using SQLAlchemy in Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/sqlalchemy/)). Then, you can pass the database ID of the new entry into the url_for parameter in `/a` so that it's redirected to some URL with this parameter set. (i.e. `/b?user_id=123`). Be aware there are multiple security issues you'll need to be aware of, since the user can just change the ID themselves.

There are lots of ways to do this. You may want to use the [Flask-WTF addon](https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) to handle some of this for you.

[Here's some snippets](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/category/sessions/) on handling sessions in Flask.

Comment: In that case, sessions will do the same, without the need of save any data in database.

Comment: @user2990084: Sessions are stored with a cookie on the client side, which I stated in the first line of my answer. You really should store data in a cookie that's used for processing in a form later since it's trivially easy to change the contents of a cookie, leading to lots of security issues. But, YMMV.

Comment: In my previous comment, I should have said "You really should NOT store data in a cookie"...

Comment: But sessions in flask are stored in server or client side? In PHP sessions are only server side. In python is different? Anyway with the secret key the user can't edit the data in the cookie.

Comment: @user2990084: It can be stored client side in a cookie (Bad if your storing form variables used later), or client side/server side using a combination of cookies to store a SessionID, and a server side database. The latter being the better option, but requires a database. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17694469/flask-save-session-data-in-database-like-using-cookies on how to do this. I edited the answer to include a link to Session handling in Flask as well.